# Why do we say 'in the air', not 'in air'?

Tags: articles

Why is 'the' used before air in the expression *in the air*? *Air* is an uncountable noun. However, 'the' (the article) precedes the word 'air'. For example: *He hit a ball in the air*. How can *air* be specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definite article can be used with both count and mass nouns. With the latter you are referring to some specific portion of it. If I were to say *The water is cold*, I have a particular portion of water in mind— perhaps the water in my laboratory beaker, or perhaps the water of the lake I am wading in. If I were to say *Water is cold*, I would mean that all water everywhere is cold, and one would immediately object that water can be warmed up, and that some water is quite hot.

Naturally, you will see *the* in conjunction with words for "big" concepts, whether physically large like geographic or planetary features, or conceptually sweeping: *the sea*, *the economy*, *the [bush](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bush#bush__6)*, and so forth. The *air* in *in the air* is also a more metaphorical usage:

> [air](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/air#air__6) 1.2. the free or unconfined space above the surface of the earth:
>   *he celebrated by tossing his hat high in the air* [ODO]

Thus, to hit something *in the air* or *into the air* is to hit it away from the earth. If I hit a [line drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drive), in which the ball is projected close to the ground, it certainly traveling *in air* in the sense of being surrounded by the mixture of gases which envelopes our planet, but not *in the air*, which would mean *towards the sky*.

Comment: so the tl;dr version is that *the air* = *the sky*, right? Now the question is why do we say *in the sky*, not *in sky*?...

Comment: @Ooker It can, but it depends on context. *The sky* refers to the firmament, whereas *the air* refers to the open space above the ground; if you throw a ball *at the sky* you are much more ambitious than if you throw it *in[to] the air*, which might just be a few centimeters above your head. An airplane *in the sky* is overhead, whereas an airplane *in the air* may have just taken off, and appear below your spot on a mountain overlooking the airport.

Comment: What if you just jump? You jump into *the air*, correct? Just like you jump into *the water*.

Answer (score 5):

In this expression, the “air” in “in the air” can be thought of as “sky”. This is sense 2.a. from thefreedictionary.com:

> **air** *(âr)*
>   
> *<sup>n.</sup>*
> 2.a. The sky
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “air” on thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/air)</sub>

Of course, the sky is usually thought of as very high up, whereas the air is anything off the ground.

So “in the air” generally means “currently somewhere above the ground”.

“The ground” presents the same situation, grammatically speaking. We're not referring to **a** specific ground, or a specific section of ground, we're referring to **the** ground in the most general sense, i.e., “the (outdoor) floor”.

---

You’ll notice that “currently somewhere above the ground” is not what you meant to indicate about the ball. There’s a reason for that, which is not the subject of your question, but is worth mentioning: When describing a movement, such as the movement of the ball from the bat to the air, it’s better to use “into” as in “He hit a ball **into** the air”.

As it is currently written, the sentence just tells us that the ball was *in the air* at the time when he hit it, not necessarily that it went *up* after he did so.

Answer (score 2):

If I say "I breathe air" then I am speaking of some non-specific body of air.  If I say "I hit the ball in the air" I am speaking of all the air in the world, which is a specific body of air.  That's why we use "the" in this context.  An analogy is "I love water" vs. "I love the water."  The first suggests that I love to drink water.  The second suggests that I love to be by or on or in the ocean, or lakes, or rivers, or some other body of water.

Comment: "[I love mountains](https://books.google.it/books?id=B2iWDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&dq=%22love+mountains%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUstv_rKPnAhVLxKYKHQiSD3gQ6AEISzAE#v=onepage&q=%22love%20mountains%22&f=false)" vs "I love the mountains" What's the difference in meaning?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Are you saying that there isn't any?

Comment: I think that "I love water" and "I love the water" could equally refer to a body of water whereas Iìd agree that the former would be more likely said for the beverage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that the difference, although subtle, is there. When you say "I love the mountains" there's a (subtle) implication of known mountains rather than all mountains. Rather analogous to loving "being on the water" and loving "being on water."

Comment: That's a good explanation! I like that.

Answer (score 0):

"He hits a ball into THE air." "AIR" here means a space above THE ground. We use "THE" before the unique things such as THE sun, THE moon, THE sky, THE ground, THE air. 
Other examples  for THE air: "Don't move. Put your hands in THE air."
                            "The balloon rose up into THE air."
"Air" also means the mixture of gasses that surrounds the earth and" we breath it for living. In this case "AIR" is uncountable noun so without "A/AN" right before it as well as no plural form. We say: AIR is one of the most important things in life.
When we refer to "AIR" in specific context THE is added.
"The bus was overcrowded . It makes THE air in the bus stuffy." I hope it help.