# Should I use "air" or "the air" when talking about waves in the context of physics?

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles, definite-article

This [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16805/103381) by @choster gives a nice explanation about using 'in the air' rather than 'in air'.

Unfortunately, when I google: [*how does sound wave travel through air*](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TwIuXoGYIc7l9QPl2QY&q=how%20does%20sound%20wave%20travel%20through%20air&oq=how%20does%20sound%20wave%20%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.3.0l6j0i10j0j0i10l2.112245.112519..119114...0.8..0.165.283.0j2......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.Gy3smIChsx8), I found that lots of guys are using ‘in air’ when talking about physics, in particular, when talking about waves.

[example_1](https://www.quora.com/How-does-sound-travel-through-air):

> Sound travels in air as a series of compressions and rarefactions.

[example_2](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/u11l1c.cfm):

> Sound waves traveling through air are indeed longitudinal waves with compressions and rarefactions.

Q: Should I use “air” or “the air” when talking about waves in the context of physics?

Comment: You should reread choster's answer and Tyler James Young's in the first link, they give the explanation as to why "in air" might be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You generally use the definite article **the** when you are referring to a specific thing and both you and the listener/reader understand which particular thing you are talking about. This is the case in the answer that you referred to: the answerer is talking about "all of the air surrounding the planet".

When talking about a thing in general, we don't use the definite article. if it's a mass noun (air, water, sugar) we don't use an indefinite article either.

Compare these two sentences:

> I don't like the cheese.
>   I don't like cheese.

The first sentence refers to a particular piece of cheese and the speaker/writer and the listener/reader both know what particular piece of cheese this refers to. The second sentence refers to cheese in general: the speaker/writer does not like cheese of any sort.

When talking about air in a scientific context, we are usually talking about air as a medium- air in general. We therefore do not use the definite article, although it would be grammatically correct to do so since, as far as this planet is concerned, air in general is the same as the air that surrounds our planet.

Looking at typical actual usages of air in a scientific context, for example as search for "[speed] of sound in air" vs. "[speed] of sound in the air", [google NGrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20sound%20in%20the%20air%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) finds very few instances where **the air** is used, and generally they are references to a specific volume or type of air, for example "the speed of sound in the air in the tube".

Comment: There are hundreds, nay thousands, of types of cheeses (in this case countable). How many types of air are there?

Comment: I think, not 100% sure, but, in the two examples cited by the OP, the definite article could be added without messing up the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "When talking about air in a scientific context, we are usually talking about air as a medium- air in general." So, the definite article is not necessary, right?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: grammatically, yes, you could add the definite article, but when used in a scientific context to refer to air as a medium (likewise water, vacuum, glass or any other medium), the definite article is rarely used. I have added a link to an ngram graph that demonstrates this.

Comment: remove "of" from [**sound in the air**](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNTuFPUkl5JlQAa6gGnyS5QKv7ZgEQ%3A1580127184709&ei=0NMuXvfyKu7JrgSRlJC4CA&q=%22sound+in+the+air%22&oq=%22sound+in+the+air%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...5117.5747.0.11316.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.qlZSxazIpI4) in your link–please include the entire phrase in your answer, not just "the air"–and the results dramatically improve

Comment: @Mari-LouA: full search phrases added, With your phrase, the number of results dramatically improve, but the relevance does not: the first few references produced by your search phrase are archaic (Francis Bacon 1561-1626, Thomas Rutherforth 1712–1771),  non-native (Bahram Esmailzadeh, Ivan Jelev Tashev) or not about air as a medium "Here, we show why supersonic surface waves produce much louder sound in the air above them".

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Many thanks to the OP's question which got me thinking</sub>

> When an object moves — whether it’s a vibrating guitar string or an exploding firecracker — it pushes on **the air molecules** closest to it.

Here the definite article is needed because it specifies *which * air molecules are affected, e.g., the ones closest to the object making the sound.

> Those displaced molecules bump into their neighbors, and then those displaced molecules bump into their neighbors. **The motion travels through *the* air** as a wave. When the wave reaches your ear, you perceive it as sound.

If the author was referring to the theory, they might have written

> ***Motion travels through air*** as a wave.

We see the same construction in the OP's example

> **Sound travels in air** as a series of compressions and rarefactions

But in the original text, the author of the article is referring *back* to the sound produced by the hypothetical guitar string or firecracker, the writer is reminding his or her reader where they are in the “story”.

> As a sound wave passes through **the air**, the air pressure in any given spot will oscillate up and down; […]

Text: [There Actually *Is* Sound in Outer Space](https://gizmodo.com/there-actually-is-sound-in-outer-space-1738420340)

Comment: Part of the problems seems to be "air" being a mass noun. If we consider "cars travel through the tunnel" or "cars travel through the tunnels" or "cars travel through tunnels" there are three quite distinct meanings. (with "cars travel through tunnel" being unacceptable because tunnel is no a mass noun)

Comment: @DukeBouvier Yes, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: With things that can be both a mass and non-mass noun all four options are valid:
"sound travels through metal"
"sound travels through metals"
"sound travels through the metal"
"sound travels through the metals"

but the specific/generic distinction is clearer.